# Elastic search querying

Tags: django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm having some issues with my elastic search querying. I have the following fields, patientid, patientfirstname, patientmidname, and patientlastname. I want to be able to enter in either one of those 4 fields and get matching results returned. So far my query works only if I use a patientid. If i type something like harry (firstname) or middle/last name it doesn't query it. Individual term querying works for each of them.

```
q = Q({"bool": { "should": [ {"term":{"patientid":text}}, {"wildcard":{"patientlastname":"*"+text+"*"}}, {"wildcard":{"patientfirstname":"*"+text+"*"}}, {"wildcard":{"patientmidname":"*"+text+"*"}} ]}})

r = Search().query(q)[0:10000]
```

Comment: Please provide mapping of your index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the matching depends on your analyzers, what I would recommend is to just use:

```
Search().query('multi_match', query=text, fields=['patientid', 'patientlastname', 'patientfirstname', 'patientmidname'])
```

which will query across those fields (you can read about different `type`s of `multi_match` query in [0]).

You just need to make sure that all the patient name fields are properly analyzed (see [1] for details)

0 - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html
1 - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/analysis.html#_index_time_analysis

Comment: That is actually what i did. It is important however for everyone to understand that multi_match only works on fields of the same type. If either one of the fields is a different type e.g. Text, Integer, Text, Text. Algolia will only match againt Text fields so the Integer field will not be mapped against.